# Refer to generic type of struct in macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I need to use an attribute of the generic type of a struct in a macro.

A slightly contrived but minimal example would be if I wanted to implement a method for a generic struct, that returned the minimum value of its generic type.

```
struct Barn<T> {
    hay: T
}

macro_rules! impl_min_hay{
    ($barntype:ident) => {
        impl $barntype {
            fn min_hay(&self) -> ????T {
                ????T::MIN
            }
        }
    }
}

type SmallBarn = Barn<i8>;
type BigBarn = Barn<i64>;

impl_min_hay!(SmallBarn);
impl_min_hay!(BigBarn);

fn main() {
    
    let barn = SmallBarn { hay: 5 };
    println!("{}", barn.min_hay());
}
```

How would I resolve from SmallBarn to get the generic type and thus it's MIN attribute?

The actual problem I am trying to solve is a change to [this macro](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/a911dbeb4a464533c9b283ab5454b00d41fbd674/polars/polars-core/src/frame/hash_join/mod.rs#L939-L971). The macro is applied to, among others, BooleanChunked, which is defined as:
`pub type BooleanChunked = ChunkedArray<BooleanType>`

And I need to use an attribute of BooleanType

Comment: Not sure how many cases are affected, but if your problem is local enough, a simple solution might be to make `impl_min_hay` accept a second parameter denoting the inner type.

Comment: I think the solution for the linked macro is to _only_ accept the type parameter as macro argument, and then use `ChunkedArray<$typeparam>` inside the macro for the full type.

Comment: Is this an example? If not why are you using a macro for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only general solution I can think of is to define a trait that allows you to get at the type parameter (the syntax for this is `<Type as Trait>::AssociatedType`):

```
trait HasHayType {
    type HayType;
}
impl<T> HasHayType for Barn<T> {
    type HayType = T;
}

macro_rules! impl_min_hay{
    ($barntype:ident) => {
        impl $barntype {
            fn min_hay(&self) -> <$barntype as HasHayType>::HayType {
                <$barntype as HasHayType>::HayType::MIN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's the complete program on play.rust-lang.org.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6fcf10c7c24c3c7b4f01354e1bc54063)

That said, once you have a trait, you don't really need the macro – you can just implement `min_hay` on the trait (this example makes use of the widely used `num-traits` crate, because this approach needs a trait for "things that have minimum values"):

```
use num_traits::Bounded;
trait HasHayType {
    type HayType: Bounded;
    fn min_hay(&self) -> Self::HayType;
}
impl<T: Bounded> HasHayType for Barn<T> {
    type HayType = T;
    fn min_hay(&self) -> T {
        T::min_value()
    }
}
```

[And here's what that looks like as a complete program.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c726d0ecd82a283c96bf8382ba2076ab)

(And of course, once you've done that too, you don't really need the separate trait either: you can inline the definition of `HasHayType` into `Barn`, using a `where` clause if you want to be able to handle `Barn`s with non-numerical hay types in addition to the ones where you'd use the macro. Presumably, though, the actual situation you have is more complex than the cut-down example you used for the question, so I gave the more complex versions in case the simplified versions wouldn't work.)

As a side note, `min_hay` doesn't actually need the `&self` parameter here; you could remove it, in order to be able to learn the minimum amount of hay without needing a barn to put it in.